# Homomorphism from $S_n$ to $D_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $k$ and $n$ be natural numbers so that $k>2$, $n>4$ and $k$ is not divisible by $3$. How many homomorphisms from the symmetric group $S_n$ to the dihedral group $D_k$ are there?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried. You can begin by working out some small examples by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three normal subgroups of $S_n$. The resulting quotients have orders $1$, $2$, and $n! $. The third option is not possible because $k$ is not divisible by $3$. So the answer is one more than the number of elements of $D_k$ of order $2$.